# Detect IE8 in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am looking how to detect `IE7` and `IE8` browser in `MVC4`, how to do that?

I find the property `Request.Browser` but it do not gives any information about browser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I advise you to use Contains method on `Request.UserAgent`

```
if (Request.UserAgent.Contains("MSIE 7.0"))
{
    // Internet Explorer 7
}
else if (Request.UserAgent.Contains("MSIE 8.0"))
{
    // Internet Explorer 8
}
```

Comment: This is what I get from Request.Headers["User-Agent"]: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you want <= 8:

```
Request.Browser.Browser == "IE" && Request.Browser.MajorVersion <= 8;
```